# Passing arguments to the generic views Django queryset

Tags: python, django

I would like to make a queryset on a **generic view** in this way:

```
 category_info = {
      'queryset' : ModelObject.objects.filter(category=category_id)
 }
```

where the `category_id` will be stated on the URL

```
 (r'^category/(?P<category_id>\d+)$', 'object_list', category_info )
```

But I don't know how to take the data from the URL and pass it to the category info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to define your own view and return the generic view from within:

urls.py:

```
(r'^category/(?P<category_id>\d+)$', 'myapp.views.category_list')
```

myapp/views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list
def category_list(request, category_id):
    queryset = ModelObject.objects.filter(category=category_id)
    return object_list(request, queryset=queryset)
```

You can also customise the generic view further, using the parameters mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list). (You may like to also verify that the category exists, throwing a 404 when it doesn't)

Comment: I needed also to add the `request` parameter, this way:
`return object_list(request, queryset=queryset)`